# Joomla FlippingBook plugin non-flash solution

Tags: flash, mobile, joomla, components

I need to create a version of an existing Joomla website that will be viewed by mobile devices, still in Joomla.
The existing website uses the [FlipingBook](http://www.page-flip-tools.com/) component in order to display certain books. The component uses Flash, and it has a non-flash SEO version that doesn't look very good, also it doesn't have the "flipping" feature that it is supposed to provide.
Another thing is that it saves and uses the books in tables of its own. My website has to use the database of the existing website.
In conclusion, I need to figure out a way to view the existing data as organised by the FlippingBook component, in a non-flash way on my mobile version website.

Can anyone suggest some solution to this issue, or maybe another component or plugin, except me creating a new Joomla component?